# Download file from Google Drive in android

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I followed [this](https://www.numetriclabz.com/integrate-google-drive-in-android-tutorial/) tutorial in my android app, and I can login, select, view file from my Google Drive account. How can I download a file to my cache folder when I know the DriveId of the file. I know I can obtain drivefile like this.

```
DriveFile driveFile = mFileId.asDriveFile();
```

Can I convert this driveFile to *File*. I tried to cast it, didn't work. In [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) link there is a method for downloading the file, but i can't find *files()* or *executeMediaAndDownloadTo* in my *Drive driveService*. Is this for an old version? I couldn't find anything useful on the internet for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result = id.asDriveFile()
                  .open(client, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null).await();
```

check status is good with

```
result.getStatus().isSuccess()
```

then access the file with

```
result.getDriveContents().getInputStream()
```

`client` is your `GoogleApiClient` instance

Write the `InputStream` to a `File` if you want to create a copy of the file.